# class initialization problem

Tags: c++

Program works fine,but memory validator reports error UNINITIALIZED READ on line CProfiles profile;

Is that "profile" definition of class CProfiles outside CProfiles body a bad programming practice ?

Here is my code:
inside profiles.cpp

```
#include "profiles.h"

CProfiles profile;  // Here it reports the problem
KeyProfile* keyProfile=&profile;    // keyProfile is later used in other classes
//-------------------------------------------------------------

CProfiles::CProfiles():forceDialog(0)
{
      oldName="";
}

int CProfiles::Init()
{   
     _chdir(PROFILES_PATH);
}

CProfiles::~CProfiles()
{
}
```

inside profiles.h

```
#define PROFILES_PATH           "Profiles"  
#include "KeyProfile.h"

class CProfiles: public KeyProfile
{

    public: 
       CProfiles();
       ~CProfiles();
       int Init();
       bool forceDialog;
       string oldName;
};

extern CProfiles profile;
```

KeyProfile.h

```
    public:
   virtual UINT GetKeyUp()      { return DIK_UP; }
   virtual UINT GetKeyDown()    { return DIK_DOWN; }
   virtual UINT GetKeyLeft()    { return DIK_LEFT; }
   virtual UINT GetKeyRight()   { return DIK_RIGHT; }
   virtual UINT GetKeyAction()  { return DIK_RETURN; }
   virtual UINT GetKeyCancel()  { return DIK_RCONTROL; }
       virtual UINT GetKeyEsc() { return DIK_ESCAPE; }
   KeyProfile(void){};
   virtual ~KeyProfile(void){};
    };
    extern KeyProfile* keyProfile;
```

Comment: Show us `KeyProfile::KeyProfile()` (and any other relevant constructors further up the inheritance chain).

Comment: class KeyProfile
{
public:
 virtual UINT GetKeyUp()  { return DIK_UP; }
 virtual UINT GetKeyDown() { return DIK_DOWN; }
 virtual UINT GetKeyLeft() { return DIK_LEFT; }
 virtual UINT GetKeyRight() { return DIK_RIGHT; }
 virtual UINT GetKeyAction() { return DIK_RETURN; }
 virtual UINT GetKeyCancel() { return DIK_RCONTROL; }
    virtual UINT GetKeyEsc() { return DIK_ESCAPE; }
 KeyProfile(void){};
 virtual ~KeyProfile(void){};
};

Comment: Sorry. Updated to original post. KeyProfile.cpp is empty. No other related constructos found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Actually I found a problem. It is the static initialization order fiasco. More information about the problem is for example here:[Constructors - How do I prevent the "static initialization order fiasco"?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.14)

And here is the solution inside my code:

```
// in profiles.cpp

//CProfiles profile; // Insted this, I access the instance through the profile() function
CProfiles& profile()    
{
    static CProfiles* ans = new CProfiles();
    return *ans;
}
KeyProfile* keyProfile=profile();
```

And I access the instance through the profile() function everywhere I need it.

Answer (score 0):

The code analyzer you are using is complaining because you have instantiated an *automatic object* in `CProfiles profiles;`. The `extern` keyword is telling the compiler that the object you are setting **external** will be created elsewhere, so the linker will find that symbol later, and make it all work. The code analyzer is letting you know that you may have forgotten to initialize your object.

Comment: So should I let it be as it is , or change it ?

Comment: @en667: It's up to you. You need to do something with the object before you read any data from it.

Comment: Thank you. Just a general question: what is more suitable practice if for example I need to do something with it sooner ?

Comment: @en667: You are OK. You want stack allocation. A common name for this is RAII. What I mean is don't try to use the object before you have done some sort of assignment or operation on the object.

Comment: I just found that in other .cpp is used: if (profile.Init()==1)  {code} with any prior use of profile. Could that cause a troubles ?

Comment: It is one of the main .cpp and in relation to code posted here it only has: #include "profiles.h" and later in the code this line  if (profile.Init()==1) {code} (nothing else related to CProfiles profile;) I used a larger call stack and that line brings memory validator there.